# remove instances from a Load Balancer, if the disk is "full"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing

i want to remove instances from a Load Balancer, if the disk is "full" (over a certain percentage) for that instance. That's why i nedd a script to do that or other solution

Answer (score 1):

Most of the instructions to achieve this are here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/mon-scripts.html#using_put_script

Essentially you'll want to set a crontab to run:

```
*/5 * * * * ~/aws-scripts-mon/mon-put-instance-data.pl --disk-space-util --disk-path=/ --from-cron
```

From there you'll want to create a CloudWatch Alarm and either terminate/stop the instance or setup an SNS topic and lambda function to perform more complex actions similar to what is described in this blog post: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/identifying-unhealthy-targets-of-elastic-load-balancer/

[image: creating a custom cloudwatch metric alarm]
[image: configuring an action on a cloudwatch alarm]

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to Randall's great answer you can also create a script in web language of your choosing that will performs the healthchecks you need and point the load balancer's healtcheck at it. If the disk is full returns a status code other than 200 and the load balancer will mark the instance as unhealthy and stop sending requests to it.

Comment: yes i think i need this script if you have please because there is no disk hcek in ELB

Comment: @hamdiHasnaoui Like I said, write it in the language of your choosing, php, nodejs, python, anything will do.